# 2014 Honda Odyssey - Maintenance Minder change oil after only 3 months

Tags: honda, oil, oil-change, odyssey

We just took our 2014 Honda Odyssey for an oil change 3 months ago, and the maintenance minder light came on.  It's not that high mileage of a vehicle (40K miles).

1. Does the Maintenance Minder actually track oil quality?  I looked at the oil on the dipstick (wiped on rag), and it's amber-ish.
2. Is the dealership using low quality oil that could cause the life of the oil to not last as long?
3. Any other things that could cause low oil life?

Comment: Was the reminder cleared during the last oil change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't say for sure how Honda's system works. However many bands use a variety of inputs to decide oil life. These may include but aren't limited to, engine load, cold start cycles, rpm, conductivity and viscosity of the oil, mileage plus more. The engine control module looks at these factors and decides when the oil needs to be change.

Comment: Spot on answer. Add to it, the minders do a pretty good job of it from my experience.